# How Do You Write 16 Bit Integers To File?

Tags: c++, windows, file

Using C++, Windows 7, Intel CPU.

What I want to do is map float values [-1, 1] to 16-bit signed values and write them to a file. The most obvious thing to do seems to be to multiply the float values by 32768 (2^16 / 2) and then simply write them. Here's what happens when I do that:

```
    std::ofstream outfile(filename.c_str());
    float hypotheticalFloat = 0.25;
    int16_t scaledVal = hypotheticalFloat*32768;
    outfile << scaledVal;
```

The octal dump command then tells me that I have

```
    $ od -cd output.pcm
    0000000   8   1   9   2
              12600   12857
```

Which seems to me like it wrote each of the int16_t value's numbers as its own byte. I would be indebted to anyone who knows what's going on here. I'm at a loss.

Comment: "each of the value's numbers"? That's not anything that makes sense. What's "a value's number"?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think he means "value's digits", i.e. write the decimal representation to file instead of the binary form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of two errors: The first is that when you open a file without a specified [openmode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), it's opening in text mode, and you want it to be binary:

```
std::ofstream outfile(filename.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

The other error is that you use the textual output operator `<<`. You need to [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) the data:

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&scaledVal), sizeof scaledVal);
```

Comment: not to mention that operator `<<` is using text mode, no matter what mode the file is opened in.

Comment: What operator should I use?

Comment: As explained in my answer, use `write()` member method of `ostream`

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator *formats* the number and prints a human readable string representation.

If you want to write actual bytes, use *unformatted* I/O:

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&scaledVal), sizeof scaledVal);
```

Comment: This worked, I'm so thrilled! ... One further question though, out of curiosity: Why is it that I could write int8_t's with the << operator?

Comment: @ElwoodHopkins: Because `int8_t` is a typedef for `signed char` and there's a special overload for `operator<<` that prints chars verbatim. It's actually a regular source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this template function useful:

```
template <typename T>
inline void writeRaw(std::ostream &stream, T const &data)
{
    stream.write((char const *) &data, sizeof(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file in "binary" mode.

And you need to use the `write` function to write the value.

```
std::ofstream outfile(filename.c_str(), ios:binary);
float hypotheticalFloat = 0.25;
int16_t scaledVal = hypotheticalFloat*32768;
outfile.write((char *)&scaledVal, sizeof(scaledVal));
```